# What does varchar(-1) mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, varchar

What is the meaning of varchar(-1) in SQL Server 2008? Is it an alternative for varchar(max)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's how to represent [varchar(max) in .net SQLDBType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx) (not explicitly stated, but length is -1)

I can't try it in SQL language in SQL Server right now for interest's sake: but I'm sure it's only for client code because varchar is normally strongly defined between 1 and 8000, but for max type it's not.

Comment: yaa...i also thnk the length of varchar(max) is -1 . when i gave sp_help to table having varchar(max) as one of the datatype , the length is displaying as -1.

Answer (score 6):

i think it is [varchar(max)](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.newusers/browse_thread/thread/5725ff64ff7d0187). I never seen it before.

Comment: I can't understand why would anyone downvote a correct answer. I know it's a very old question, but I upvoted anyway.

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 6):

It is only SQL Query Analyser which displays -1 instead of Max. In design view, still you can see it as Max.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) says:

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>   Variable-length, non-Unicode character
>   data. n can be a value from 1 through
>   8,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.

So -1 isn't technically valid.  It might work, but I wouldn't use it if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes man... it´s a varchar(MAX)