# Sql Server 2008 NVARCHAR length -1

Tags: sql-server-2008

what does it means if the length is -1 ?

here is my tbl structure

```
Name    nvarchar    no  -1
```

Comment: I think this is display only. Here's another SO page: [What does varchar(-1) mean?][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713093/what-does-varchar-1-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As JNK pointed out in the comments, it means `MAX`:

```
Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx):

> -1 = Column data type is varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), or xml.

Answer (score 4):

`-1` in `sys.columns` indicates `(max)`.

I confirmed this by making a test table and querying `sys.columns`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t (testcol nvarchar(max))

select *
from sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('dbo.t')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another SO page (concerning varchar instead of nvarchar, but same answer): [What does varchar(-1) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713093/what-does-varchar-1-mean)