# Actual size of Varchar(-1)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my existing database for one column it is specified as `varchar(-1)`. What will be the actual size of this.

Even if the text is more, I can see only 500 characters are stored against it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: [might this help?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99394/why-do-we-have-negative-length-for-character-maximum-length-for-geography-and-va). A summary, `-1` means maximal size supported.

Comment: Its MAX, if you see a 500 char limit then thats down to whatever your looking at it in performing truncation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713093/what-does-varchar-1-mean