# Declaring a table with a negative length varchar column

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I am working with a table which contains a column defined as varchar with a length of -1 and nullable.

What would be the reason to declare a varchar field with length of -1?

If this design/definition has a name, could you point me on the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right-click on the table, select Script Table As >> Create To >> wherever is convenient, delete the index definitions and other extraneous details, and copy the DDL into your question as text, please.  Where do you see the "-1", anyway?

Comment: I see the -1 with the properties for my table (I select the table then Alt + F1), it shows all the column names, type, compute, length, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server?   Can you post a screenshot?   It is not possible to create a varchar with length -1 in SQL Server.   At least, my SQL Server won't let me do it.

Comment: Sadly I just found an answer to this,  I wish I had found this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713093/what-does-varchar-1-mean

Comment: That means the column is varchar(max). Look at the max_length column in sys.columns for the column. When it is max it will have a value of -1. You can't however specify that manually.